# received "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response" for connecting to web socket

Tags: swift, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

Hi I’m getting "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response” error when connect to websocket server developed in java spring boot. Java client is able to successfully connect and send message,

Below is our code implementation

import StompClientLib

```
   var socketClient = StompClientLib()
    let completedWSURL = "ws://192.168.1.37:8080/iostest/chat"
     let Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:completedWSURL)! as URL)
    socketClient.openSocketWithURLRequest(request:Request, delegate: self as        StompClientLibDelegate)
```

Error response is
Error Domain=SRWebSocketErrorDomain Code=2133 "Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Sec-WebSocket-Accept response}

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SockJS, use suffix `/websocket`

Example: `ws://192.168.1.37:8080/iostest/chat/websocket`